# PAW: command not found

Tags: homebrew

I need to install PAW on my system for some analysis. I am working on a Macintosh system (Sierra), I tried installing it through Homebrew : brew cask install paw . The installation was successful, but when I run the script which calls for using paw to plot some data, I get the following error:

PAW: command not found

Any suggestions how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

PAW may not be in your path. I would first type 'which PAW' and see if it returns with a path to PAW. If it does try using whole path to run PAW or at that directory structure to your path.

Ex. if 'which paw' returns /usr/bin/paw try /usr/bin/paw to run PAW.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, when I type "which paw" at the terminal, it dosen't return anything! @john